Action server does not receive goals after the first one has terminated
I'm on ROS2 Humble using python. I am building an node to process the feedback of the action server of a different node. Let's call the first node Tracker and the second one Detector.
Tracker implements an action server providing all the possible callbacks, in a MultiThreadedExecutor with ReentrantCallbackGroup as callback group for those callbacks. A similar arrangement is also present in Detector. Tracker also has an action client in order to send to Detector the specific goal we want to track the feedback of. Detector instead has a subscriber that updates a message object from which it detects what it needs to detect.
The problem is that after the first goal to Tracker has terminated (I send the goal via terminal using ros2 action send_goal /tracker_action_name <tracker goal object> and cancel it with ctrl+c) if I try to send a new goal, either in the same or in a different terminal, the new goal is not received by Tracker.
The terminal remain stuck in Waiting for an action server to become available... and nothing changes. The Tracker's callback for the goal request is not triggered and it is necessary to restart Tracker to process a new goal.
Using ros2 action list the action is still listed and with ros2 action info /tracker_action_name I can see that Tracker still provides the server. Yet, it remain unresponsive to new goals.
This behavior is not present in Detector. Detector has no problem receiving subsequent goals or multiple goals at the same time, despite sharing almost the same structure of Tracker. It has a problem with rclpy.wait_for_message.wait_for_message which occasionally does not wait for the time provided, but I don't think it's relevant for this case.
Tracker code is this. I have removed all unnecessary code that still reproduce the behavior and added logging.
import rclpy.client
import rclpy, rclpy.node, rclpy.action, rclpy.executors
from rclpy.callback_groups import ReentrantCallbackGroup
import time

class Tracker(rclpy.node.Node):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__('tracker')
    self.log_info('Setting up node')

    self.action_server = rclpy.action.ActionServer(
      self,
      custom_interface.action.Tracking,
      "track",
      goal_callback=self.goal_callback,
      handle_accepted_callback=self.handle_accepted_callback,
      cancel_callback=self.cancel_callback,
      execute_callback=self.execute_callback,
      callback_group=ReentrantCallbackGroup()
    )

    self.log_info('Setup complete')
  
  def goal_callback(self, goal_request:custom_interface.action.Tracking.Goal):
    self.log_debug('Accepting new goal') 
    return rclpy.action.GoalResponse.ACCEPT
  
  def handle_accepted_callback(self, goal_handle:rclpy.action.server.ServerGoalHandle):
    self.log_debug('Starting new goal')
    goal_handle.execute()

  def cancel_callback(self, goal_handle:rclpy.action.server.ServerGoalHandle):
    self.log_debug('Received cancel request')
    return rclpy.action.CancelResponse.ACCEPT
  
  def execute_callback(self, goal_handle:rclpy.action.server.ServerGoalHandle):
    self.log_info('Action started')

    detector_action_client = rclpy.action.ActionClient(
      self,
      custom_interface.action.DetectorAction,
      '/detector_action_name',
      callback_group=ReentrantCallbackGroup()
    )

    self.log_debug('Waiting for detector action server...')

    detector_action_client.wait_for_server()

    self.log_debug('Detector action server online')

    goal_msg = custom_interface.action.DetectorAction.Goal()

    self.log_debug('Sending goal request...')

    detector_goal_future = detector_action_client.send_goal_async(
      goal_msg,
      feedback_callback=self.detector_action_feedback)

    # wait for the server to respond to the goal request
    rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, detector_goal_future)
    
    detector_client_goal_handle = detector_goal_future.result()

    if detector_client_goal_handle is None:
      self.log_error('Detector action server did not respond to the request')
      goal_handle.abort()
      return custom_interface.action.Tracking.Result()

    if not detector_client_goal_handle.accepted:
      self.log_error('Detector action server rejected the request')
      goal_handle.abort()
      return custom_interface.action.Tracking.Result()

    self.log_debug('Detector action server accepted the request')

    # let it detect
    get_result_future = detector_client_goal_handle.get_result_async()


    while rclpy.ok() and not goal_handle.is_cancel_requested:
      rclpy.spin_once(self)
      self.log_debug('Processing')
      time.sleep(0.5)
      pass

    cancel_future = detector_client_goal_handle.cancel_goal_async()
    rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, cancel_future)
    
    detector_action_client.destroy()

    result = custom_interface.action.Tracking.Result()
    goal_handle.succeed()
    self.log_debug('Action completed')
    return result
  
  def detector_action_feedback(self, feedback:custom_interface.action._custom_action.DetectorAction_FeedbackMessage):
    self.log_debug(f'Timestamp: {feedback.feedback.header.stamp}')


  def log_info(self, log: str) -> None:
    self.get_logger().info(log)

  def log_debug(self, log: str) -> None:
    self.get_logger().debug(log)

  def log_error(self, log: str) -> None:
    self.get_logger().error(log)

  def log_warn(self, log: str) -> None:
    self.get_logger().warn(log)

def main(args=None):
  rclpy.init(args=args)
  tracker = Tracker()
  executor = rclpy.executors.MultiThreadedExecutor()
  executor.add_node(tracker)
  try:
    executor.spin()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()


The solution provided by the user fujitatomoya on an issue I opened on the official ROS2 github repository seems to work fine.
The problem seems to be caused by the function rclpy.spin_until_future_complete. By turning the execute_callback into an async method and using await with the other async methods it is possible to avoid using it. Here is an example.
From what I understood, that function add and remove the node from the global executor for its duration, but does not restore the previous executor. Therefore, since nodes can only have a single executor at any given time, the node cannot have any other callback executed.
I tested it by restoring manually the executor at the end of the function as in:
    goal_handle.succeed()
    self.log_info('Action terminated')

    if self.executor_backup is not None:
      self.executor_backup.add_node(self)
    
    return result

And this correction also fixed the problem in this example code. Both solutions also work perfectly in my own original code.
